# How to Inject Dependency to Meanjs Modules?

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, meanjs

I am Injecting Dependency to Meanjs Modules For the First time.
I see something confusing Dependency Injection at My research

Example(i am Trying to Inject): **I need to Inject a spinner to all of my modules**

Steps I did:

1. Do bower install angular-spinkit --save - Done
2. Add the spinkit Js and Css files to Public/all.js - Done
3. Do Dependency Injection @ Registering Module  -Done

This is my code:

```
var ApplicationConfiguration = (function() {
    // Init module configuration options
    var applicationModuleName = 'mean';
    var applicationModuleVendorDependencies = ['ngResource', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.utils','angular-spinkit'];//added spinkit

    // Add a new vertical module
    var registerModule = function(moduleName, dependencies) {

        // Create angular module
        angular.module(moduleName, dependencies || []);

        // Add the module to the AngularJS configuration file
        angular.module(applicationModuleName).requires.push(moduleName);
    };

    return {
        applicationModuleName: applicationModuleName,
        applicationModuleVendorDependencies: applicationModuleVendorDependencies,
        registerModule: registerModule
    };
})();
```

When I did all these things to Inject a Dependency all of my output is gone. What steps I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

for mean.js there you will find `**.module.js` under every module of your `public/modules` folder. For an example, try `users` module. There is a `users.client.module.js` file. There you can declare your dependencies. Like:

```
'use strict';

// Use Applicaion configuration module to register a new module
ApplicationConfiguration.registerModule('users', ['dependency1', 'dependency2', .....]);
```

Comment: Hi @najmul-hosain I am trying to inject the angular-file-upload directive in the same manner, within the users.client.module.js, but my output is still all blank, nothing shows up on the site. Can you please tell me why this could be happening? I have installed angular-file-upload using npm and done nothing else after that.

Comment: @monlogish you need to inject `FileUploader ` service into the controller. [See More](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload/wiki/Introduction#usage)

Comment: Thanks @najmul-hosain, but I managed to solve this, the problem was simply that meanjs was not reading the JS files linked with the directive. So I switched them to a different directory and got it working. Also I am using Daniel Farid's angular-file-upload so FileUploader was not required.